# Own implementation of ICollection<T> in Entity Framework possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections

Normally POCO Classes in EF look more or less like this:

```
public partial class ThingEntity 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Thing> things{ get; set; }
}
```

They always use ICollection.

If I wanted to have more methods on the ICollection, would it be bad to write my own implementation of ICollection? I read somewhere that you shouldn't use`List<T>` instead of `ICollection<T>`, but what if I have my own implementation of ICollection?

Comment: The point of these classes is to map the objects to your db tables based on the PK and FK relationship of your tables. As long as you have designed your DB correctly, you shouldn't really have any need to change.   I can see places where you might wish to extend, but you can use tools like Automapper to do this kind of thing for you. Have you an example of where/why you might want to roll your own.

Comment: Do you have examples of the extra methods you want to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the collection that you want. In fact, in all my models I use `List<T>`, and this is really an usual pattern. In fact that's an interface, and, in the end, you need a concrete implementation of that interface.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. After an hour of trying to write an implemented class with useful methods I realized that I could just write extension methods for ICollection lol

Comment: You can also create a new interface inheriting from ICollection, and write the extension methods for the new interface, if you don't want the extension methods to appear elsewhere.

Comment: I don't think that those will bother me in other Collections :D

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write an implemented class, but aften an hour I realized that I could just write Extension Methods for `ICollection<T>`. That's much easier and I won't have to replace the ICollections everywhere to get the methods I need.

And this helped me to write extension methods for generic lists:
[How to create extension method on generic collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380645/how-to-create-extension-method-on-generic-collection)